# web3js.ai (artificial intelligence?) AI functionality/capabilities in web3?

Tags: web3js

I refer to the file web3js.ai in the beta release. Does the file web3js.ai refer to artificial intelligence capabilities?

Comment: It might help if you could link to the file in question.

Comment: Nevermind, I found it in https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.ai is the extension for Adobe Illustrator. The file in question is a logo. `web3js.jpg` and `web3js.svg` are other representations of the same logo.